# Are there any examples of non-holomorphic line bundles?

Tags: complex-geometry, line-bundles

I am working on a complex geometry course.

I want to know some examples of non-holomorphic complex line bundles on complex manifolds, i.e. line bundles that do not admit a holomorphic structure.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: see this:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7304/complex-vector-bundles-that-are-not-holomorphic